# How to set a category axis title dynamically?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz, kendo-chart

I need to set a Kendo UI stock chart category axis and value axis titles dynamically using options or setoptions.

Can any one provide me a working example?

Comment: Can you add some code that we can perhaps look at in JSFiddle or something like that?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/nejawahe/6/edit?html,console,output  here is the small example of what i actullay need @Jacques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically change the titles like this:

```
var stockChart = $("#stock-chart").data("kendoStockChart");
stockChart.options.valueAxis[0].title.text = "Your new value axis title here";
stockChart.options.categoryAxis[0].title.text = "Your new column axis title here";
stockChart.refresh();
```